# React route with persistent drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Let's say I have a React app (with React Router 4) with the following components and routes:

- `App` (`/`)

  - `Toolbar` - A fixed toolbar

    - `NavButton` - A button whose appearance and behavior depends on the current route (see below)
  - `MainMenu` - A temporary drawer that pops out from the side to navigate between top-level routes
  - `Admin` (`/admin`)

    - `Sidenav` - A navigation drawer that is open all of the time on large screens and can be toggled on small screens. Clicking on items in the `Sidenav` navigates to different sub-routes under `/admin`
    - `Content` (`/admin/<xyz>`)
  - `Public` (`/public`)

    - `Content`

The behavior of the `NavButton` should be the following:

- On a large screen:

  - it should always be a hamburger icon that opens the `MainMenu`.
- On a small screen: (except for the first condition, this is similar to the experience on the Gmail mobile app)

  - if there is no `Sidenav`, it should display a hamburger icon that opens the `MainMenu`.
  - if the `Sidenav` is closed, it should display a back icon that opens the `Sidenav`.
  - if the `Sidenav` is open, it should display a hamburger icon that opens the `MainMenu`.

The `/admin` and `/public` routes are just examples. There are many more, some of which have `Sidenav`s and some of which don't.

My question is this: what is the React way to manage the UI state here and wire all of the components and routes together? It feels like `App` should be responsible for keeping track of whether the sidenav is open, so it can pass that information to `Toolbar` and others, but it also seems like `App` *shouldn't* be in charge of managing which of its potential children have or don't have `Sidenav`s. Also, how can props get passed down from `App` to some child when there's a `Route` in between?

Note: I'm fairly new to React and certainly not married to the component structure above; it's just for illustration.

Comment: For the record, I know that I could just make both `NavButton` and `Sidenav` into 'smart' components by connecting them to a redux store and simply reacting to changes in `state.isScreenBig` and `state.isSidenavActive`. But that seems sleazy. Plus, it doesn't cover the case when `state.isSidenavActive === true` and the user navigates from `/admin` to `/public`. Who is responsible for setting `state.isSidenavActive` back to `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It feels like App should be responsible for keeping track of whether the sidenav is open

True. The child components should always be presentational (pure/dumb) components.

> App shouldn't be in charge of managing which of its potential children have or don't have Sidenav

I wouldn't call it "in charge". It is simply keeping the state of the application. The user is in charge, by clicking the hamburger button.

> how can props get passed down from App to some child when there's a Route in between?

Why not? You can use `render` instead of `component`. For example:

```
let Parent = (props)=> {
 <Route 
   path="/pizza" 
   render={()=> <Pizza topping={props.topping} />}  />
}
```